# Differential representation of binary curve as a public key

Tags: elliptic-curves

Given elliptic curve $E$ over binary field $k$, a public key is the pair $(x,y)$ in $E$ and $x$ and $y$ in $k$.  The differential representation of $(x,y)$ is $w = x + y$.

What security implications are there from using $w$ as the public key, rather than $(x,y)$?

Assume the curve is BBE251 (http://binary.cr.yp.to/bbe-20090604.pdf).

Comment: Did you see the bottom of page 4 of the linked article?

Comment: The bottom of page 4 is the beginning of the section "How these speeds were achieved: high level".